# Is it possible to pass parameters when using 'def_erb_method'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

My current code is this.

```
<%= render 'codes/code', {:code => code, :icon_photo => code.community.community_icon} %>
```

I tried to use 'def_erb_method', so I changed the code to this

```
<%#= raw render_code(code), {:code => code, :icon_photo => code.community.community_icon}  %>
```

**codes_helper.rb**

```
module CodesHelper
  extend ERB::DefMethod

  def_erb_method('render_code(code)', "#{Rails.root}/app/views/codes/_code.html.erb")
end
```

However, I got this error back:(

```
undefined local variable or method `icon_photo'
```

I cannot pass the parameters when using 'def_erb_method'?

Comment: Not sure why you want to use `def_erb_method` instead of `render :partial => 'code', :locals => {..}`, however for `erb` you need to set instance variables like `@code = @code; @icon_photo = @code.community.community_icon;`

Comment: @RAJ... Thanks for a reply. It was working fine even if I didn't use instance variable:( thats so weird. The reason why I want to use 'def_erb_method' is to speeding it up to load a page. I was using too many partial so that it made it so slow...